# How to send a directory of logs to graylog

Tags: logging, graylog2

I would like to send Coldfusion logs to Graylog. I already have syslog being sent to it. Coldfusion logs to several different files all located in one directory. How would I get these all into coldfusion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concept of a [collector sidecar](http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.4/pages/collector_sidecar.html). This uses a small logshipper daemon on the remote machine where the logs reside and forwards them to the graylog server. The collector sidecar is fully manageable and configurable from the graylog server ui.